# Best Way to avoid Reinsertion of data in ASP.net on Page Refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know what is the best way to avoid the reinsertion of data in ASP.net.

I am currently doing

```
Response.Redirect('PageURL');
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Unless you provide more information on exactly *where* your insertion code is my answer can't really get any better...

Answer (score 2):

Don't put your insertion code in the `Page_Load` method, or if you are, make sure you are checking `Page.IsPostBack` first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, normally we have an *identity autoincrement* number id, wich should be sent back to your form after the insertion. So you just have to check on server if that number is > 0 and execute an `update` instead of an `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect solution is valid. This pattern is called **Post/Redirect/Get**.

> Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) is a web development design pattern that
>   prevents some duplicate form submissions, creating a more intuitive
>   interface for user agents (users). PRG implements bookmarks and the
>   refresh button in a predictable way that does not create duplicate
>   form submissions.
>
> When a web form is submitted to a server through an HTTP POST request,
>   a web user that attempts to refresh the server response in certain
>   user agents can cause the contents of the original HTTP POST request
>   to be resubmitted, possibly causing undesired results, such as a
>   duplicate web purchase.
>
> To avoid this problem, many web developers use the PRG pattern[1] —
>   instead of returning a web page directly, the POST operation returns a
>   redirection command. The HTTP 1.1 specification introduced the HTTP
>   303 ("See other") response code to ensure that in this situation, the
>   web user's browser can safely refresh the server response without
>   causing the initial HTTP POST request to be resubmitted. However most
>   common commercial applications in use today (new and old alike) still
>   continue to issue HTTP 302 ("Found") responses in these situations.
>   Use of HTTP 301 ("Moved permanently") is usually avoided because
>   HTTP-1.1-compliant browsers do not convert the method to GET after
>   receiving HTTP 301, as is more commonly done for HTTP 302.[2] However,
>   HTTP 301 may be preferred in cases where it is not desirable for POST
>   parameters to be converted to GET parameters and thus be recorded in
>   logs.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get